# preg_replace - How to match a specific number

Tags: php, preg-replace

I got a slightly tricky preg_replace that I cannot figure out.

The string could be something like 2:456:982:12:89:

Let's say I want to remove just the "2:" and replace it with nothing.

Here is what I have with $focus_chat being "2":

```
preg_replace('/:' . $focus_chat . ':/', ':', $unfocus_chat);
```

Now, this would work if the 2: was in the middle of the string.  The problem with this is that the 2: will not have a : first since it is at the beginning of the string.

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: What are the values of `$focus_chat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say: Beginning of string (that is `^`) or `:`:

```
preg_replace('/(^|:)' . $focus_chat . '(:|$)/', ':', $unfocus_chat);
```

Also added end of string (`$`) for the second delimiter.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I also had to check if the first character of the string was ':' and replace it with nothing.